# How to always enable numlock by default on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, numlock

I tried to change `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard` > `InitialKeyboardIndicators` to `2147483650` and it enabled numlock. However, if I lock my computer (numlock still active on logon screen) and login numlock gets disabled.

Is there a way to make it not lose the setting? Or a way to run a script everytime I unlock my computer so I can enable it that way?

> When I turn the computer on numlock is ON. In the logon screen it is ON, after the login it is ON. If I lock the screen it is ON, if I unlock it switches to OFF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I solved like this:

- Created a program to enable NumLock when run that runs without a window (https://github.com/brunolm/NumLock)
- Created a scheduled task

  - General

    - "Run only when user is logged on"
    - "Run with highest privileges"
  - Triggers

    - "On workstation unlock of any user"
  - Actions

    - "Start a program" (NumLock.exe)

Comment: Thank you for saving me from windows 'experience', in year 2019 you must use a external app to re-enable NumLock if it happens you remapped the key to something else...

Comment: Thank you! I've tried the Registry Tweaks, but for some reason, they get reverted. And I don't want to disable Fast Startup just to make sure NumLock is on after logging in. Your solution is what I've been looking for!

Comment: Nice solution.  I had to sign and recompile to prevent the UAC message every time.  Might not be a bad idea to add a certificate that could be installed to make this play nice out of the box.

Answer (score 7):

> First, head to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Keyboard. Double-click
>   the “InitialKeyboardIndicators” value in the right pane and set it to
>   “2”.
>
> Next, expand the “HKEY_USERS” folder. You’ll now need to repeat the
>   above process several times, changing the InitialKeyboardIndicators
>   value under each folder inside the HKEY_USERS folder.
>
> Start by going to HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard, and
>   changing the InitialKeyboardIndicators value to 2. Next, repeat the
>   process for the folder below the .DEFAULT folder–it’ll start with an
>   “S-“.
>
> Repeat this process for the remaining folders inside HKEY_USERS,
>   changing the Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators setting
>   under each one.
>
> Next, **shut down**, then boot the computer back up again. When you
>   reach the login screen, press the Num Lock key once to enable it.
>   Don’t log into the computer. From the login screen, click the power
>   button and select “Shut down” to shut down the computer again.
>
> Boot the computer back up and Num Lock will be enabled on the login
>   screen. It seems that this puts Fast Startup into a state where it
>   will automatically enable Num Lock at every boot.
>
> https://www.howtogeek.com/244606/how-to-enable-num-lock-automatically-when-your-computer-boots/

Comment: @LSxCPU - As you wish.  When you improve the formatting I will come back and reverse my vote.  At a minumim your answer should have a list of steps, contains screenshots, and information to determine the SID of the current user profile.  This will allow the author to modify just the HKEY_USERS keys required to make NUM_KEY enabled by default and for their current user.  *That is my minumim expectations for an answer to this particular question.*

Answer (score 4):

About the value: InitialKeyboardIndicators = "X"

Where X can have the following values:

```
"0" - Caps Lock / Num Lock / Scroll Lock - All Off
"1" - Caps Lock - On
"2" - Num Lock - On
"4" - Scroll Lock - On
```

It is also possible to configure combinations of all of them, these are the values:

```
"3" - Caps Lock / Num Lock - On
"5" - Caps Lock / Scroll Lock - On
"6" - Num Lock / Scroll Lock - On
"7" - Caps Lock / Num Lock / Scroll Lock - All activated
```

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2020/02/windows-activar-teclado-numerico-iniciar.html

Comment: For anyone wondering: If you add the numbers together of the combinations, you get the results that must be in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative I develoeped when one of the Win10 updates wasn't remembering `Numlock` state -- remap the keyboard so the numeric keypad keys send "top row" scancodes, which aren't modifed by the state of `Numlock`. Copy the following in to any text editor, save a `.reg` file, then right-click & `Merge`.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"ScanCode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,02,00,4f,00,03,\
  00,50,00,04,00,51,00,05,00,4b,00,06,00,4c,00,07,00,4d,00,08,00,47,00,09,00,\
  48,00,0a,00,49,00,0b,00,52,00,34,00,53,00,00,00,00,00
```